Split text elements when space runs out
I have some views that take a basic string, then locates all tags, links, and text elements. Then I have a custom layout that positions views from left to right and top to bottom. Currently, if the same type of element in the components array exceeds the horizontal space then it automatically splits and moves to the next line adding "-" in the previous line. However, the problem arises when 2 different components - tags, links, or text blocks, are on the same line; this causes components to occupy their own line if there isn't enough horizontal space.
For example:
Works correctly:

Fails - too little horizontal space moves to next line:

import SwiftUI

private let linkDetector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)

struct HustleInlineLink: View {
    let text: String
    let links: [NSTextCheckingResult]
    
    init (_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString
        let wholeString = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsText.length)
        links = linkDetector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: wholeString)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HustleInlineLinkView(text: text, links: links)
    }
}

struct HustleInlineLinkView: View {
    @State var showProfile: Bool = false
    @State var selectedUser: String? = nil
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var popRoot: PopToRoot
    
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case link(String, URL)
        case username(String, String)
    }

    let text: String
    let components: [Component]

    init(text: String, links: [NSTextCheckingResult]) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString
        
        var components: [Component] = []
        var index = 0
        for result in links {
            if result.range.location > index {
                let sub_str = nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))
                let ats = separateTextAndTags(inputString: sub_str)
              
                ats.forEach { element in
                    if element.contains("@") {
                        components.append(.username(element, element))
                    } else {
                        components.append(.text(element))
                    }
                }
            }
            components.append(.link(nsText.substring(with: result.range), result.url!))
            index = result.range.location + result.range.length
        }
        if index < nsText.length {
            let sub_str = nsText.substring(from: index)
            
            let ats = separateTextAndTags(inputString: sub_str)
            ats.forEach { element in
                if element.contains("@") {
                    components.append(.username(element, element))
                } else {
                    components.append(.text(element))
                }
            }
        }
        self.components = components
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomLayoutSec {
            ForEach(Array(components.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { _, component in
                switch component {
                case .text(let text):
                    Text(verbatim: text).font(.subheadline).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
                            
                        })
                case .link(let text, _):
                    Text(verbatim: text).foregroundColor(.blue).font(.subheadline)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
                            //do something
                        })
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                            //open link
                        })
                case .username(let text, _):
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text(text)
                            .font(.subheadline).bold()
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomLayoutSec: Layout {
    var alignment: Alignment = .leading
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)

        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            var rowWidth = CGFloat.zero
            for (i, subview) in row.enumerated() {
                if i > 0 {
                    rowWidth += spacing
                }
                rowWidth += subview.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
            }
            width = max(width, rowWidth)
            if index == (rows.count - 1) {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
            } else {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
            }
        }
        return .init(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = bounds.origin
        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for row in rows {
            let leading: CGFloat = bounds.maxX - maxWidth
            let trailing = bounds.maxX - (row.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                
                if view == row.last {
                    return partialResult + width
                }
                return partialResult + width + spacing
            })
            let center = (trailing + leading) / 2
            
            origin.x = (alignment == .leading ? leading : alignment == .trailing ? trailing : center)
            
            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        
            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing)
        }
    }
    
    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin
        
        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            
            if (origin.x + viewSize.width + spacing) > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            } else {
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
            row.removeAll()
        }
        
        return rows
    }
}

extension [LayoutSubviews.Element] {
    func maxHeight(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGFloat {
        return self.compactMap { view in
            return view.sizeThatFits(proposal).height
        }.max() ?? 0
    }
}

func separateTextAndTags(inputString: String) -> [String] {
    var resultArray: [String] = []
    var currentToken = ""

    for character in inputString {
        if character == "@" {
            if !currentToken.isEmpty {
                resultArray.append(currentToken)
                currentToken = ""
            }
            currentToken += String(character)
        } else if character.isWhitespace {
            if currentToken.count > 1 && currentToken.hasPrefix("@") {
                resultArray.append(currentToken)
                currentToken = ""
            }
            currentToken += String(character)
        } else {
            currentToken += String(character)
        }
    }

    if !currentToken.isEmpty {
        resultArray.append(currentToken)
    }

    return resultArray
}


This is happening because you are dividing up the text into chunks and then laying out the text chunks. For example, in the text you show in your screenshots, the layout receives just 3 subviews. Each subview (text chunk) gets a rectangular frame.
It is not possible for a subview to have a frame with a non-rectangular shape. Specifically, a frame cannot have a shape that starts halfway along one line and then continues with full width after that.
If you want the layout to work this way, you need to use smaller chunks. In fact, you need to use individual words. So instead of grouping all the words of the same type into one subview, they need to be treated individually.
Splitting the text this way can be done using the String .split function, your function separateTextAndTags may not be needed any more:
//let ats = separateTextAndTags(inputString: sub_str)
let ats = sub_str.split(separator: " ")

ats.forEach { element in
    if element.contains("@") {
        components.append(.username(String(element), String(element)))
    } else {
        components.append(.text(String(element)))
    }
}

It is also necessary to specify the word spacing when creating the layout:
CustomLayoutSec(spacing: 4) {
    // ...
}


As you can see, the link still starts on a new line, because there are no spaces in the link. If you want this to begin on the previous line immediately after the previous word then you could consider allowing the string to be split on other characters too (such as hyphens or slashes), or you could even split it letter-by-letter. However, it will then be more difficult to add markup, for example, if a single link is formed from multiple pieces.
The answer to How to prevent SwiftUI from adding additional hyphen characters inside text? has an example of a custom Layout that works letter-by-letter. As a different approach altogether, you could consider using a single String with embedded Markdown, or an AttributedString.

Thanks for all your help, possibly you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78282968/video-player-in-tabview-unexpectedly-plays
