Video Player in TabView unexpectedly plays
I have a basic tab view that can contain an array of images and videos in different order. Currently the video player does not play when the video view becomes the current tab. Sometimes an image can be displayed but the audio for the video player still plays. How do I make a simple tab view that can have Images and videos in any order and plays videos when they becomes the current tab and pauses them when the tab is switched?
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher
import AVFoundation

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var content: [uploadContent] = [uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: true, imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/messages%2F19EAAFB0-0AC1-4100-88DC-F9980531D559?alt=media&token=5b206605-94e2-43f3-9dfb-1922cfecc989"),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: true, imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/messages%2F01659DB0-C97D-4FB3-A0B4-0F0302FA463B?alt=media&token=9e5b0553-c081-443e-a263-7e0e81630281")]

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(Array(content.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, content in
                if let url = content.imageURL {
                    HStack {
                        KFImage(URL(string: url))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(height: 300)
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(5).tag(index)
                } else if let url = content.videoURL {
                    HStack {
                        VideoWrapper(url: url).frame(height: 300)
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(5).tag(index)
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always)).frame(height: 310)
    }
}

struct VideoWrapper: View {
    let url: URL
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    @State var viewID = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: $player).scaledToFill().id(viewID)
        }
        .onAppear {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            player.isMuted = false
            viewID.toggle()
            self.player.play()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.player.pause()
        }
    }
}


//not important for question

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
struct uploadContent: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var isImage: Bool
    var videoURL: URL?
    var imageURL: String?
}


I made a few adjustments. The most important bit is that onAppear and onDisappear don't necessarily get called when a TabView changes pages. Instead, you can rely on the selection to tell whether it's the current page. Then, I load the AVPlayer based on that selection state.
See inline comments.
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var content: [uploadContent] = [uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: true, imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/messages%2F19EAAFB0-0AC1-4100-88DC-F9980531D559?alt=media&token=5b206605-94e2-43f3-9dfb-1922cfecc989"),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: false, videoURL: URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/stories%2F73F8CF05-39AB-4A8F-AAEF-C70C9A57B22D.mp4?alt=media&token=5b5a63e3-e5af-4e2f-84c4-416abd554b84")!),
                                           uploadContent(isImage: true, imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/messages%2F01659DB0-C97D-4FB3-A0B4-0F0302FA463B?alt=media&token=9e5b0553-c081-443e-a263-7e0e81630281")]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(Array(content.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, content in
                Group {
                    if let url = content.imageURL {
                        HStack {
                            AsyncImage(url: (URL(string: url)))
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(height: 300)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    } else if let url = content.videoURL {
                        HStack {
                            VideoWrapper(url: url,
                                         isSelected: selection == index)
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(5)
                .tag(index)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always)).frame(height: 310)
    }
}

struct VideoWrapper: View {
    let url: URL
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    @State private var player: AVPlayer? // <-- Don't bother loading with an incorrect value
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let player {
                VideoPlayer(player: $player)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
        .task(id: isSelected) {
            if isSelected {
                if player == nil {
                    player = AVPlayer(url: url) // <-- Load the player if necessary
                    player?.isMuted = false
                }
                await self.player?.seek(to: .zero) // <-- Always rewind
                self.player?.play() // <-- Start
            } else {
                self.player?.pause() // <-- pause when we're off screen
            }
        }
    }
}


//not important for question

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer? // <-- now is Optional to match the parent view
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}

